# Strange behavior of javascript &&

Tags: javascript

I am using below method for validating that one of radio button must be selected.

```
function validateForm(){
    var searchType = document.getElementsByName("form1:searchType");
    var a = !(searchType[0].checked);
    var b = !(searchType[1].checked);
    if(a&&b){
        alert('Please select search type');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In above method searchType is radio button which is creating two buttons. It works fine that is shows alert message if none of the two radio buttons are selected but it show alert message even when second of the radio button is selected. Any idea please?

Comment: assuming your var a and var b lines are working properly, you need if(! (a || b)){
  alert...
}

Comment: @ DotNetNukeLab: if i use if(!(a||b)){alet ..} then alert message will shown even when none of the radio button is selected.

Comment: are you sure this code doesn't work? can you debug a bit more? e.g. put some alerts after those `var a = !....` stuff...

Comment: Is this a literal copy of your code? I will say there must be a typo in the original code somewhere. I will recommend to lint(http://www.javascriptlint.com/) the original code for simple syntactic errors and debug(chome dev. tools, firebug for firefox, also ie9 comes with handy dev. tools) it to look for logic errors.

Comment: Something else is the problem. See my edited answer for test case you can reproduce it in there and post new link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function validateForm(){
    var searchType = document.getElementsByName("form1:searchType");
    var a = !(searchType[0].checked);
    var b = !(searchType[1].checked);
    if(a&&b){
        alert('Please select search type');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

</script>


</head>

<body>

<form name="form1">

<input type="radio" name="form1:searchType" /> male
<input type="radio" name="form1:searchType" /> female
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="validateForm()" >

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

i am using your function in this code and its working fine, it may help you

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need to use the **or** operator, not **and** - when using `&&` it will be true only when *both* conditions are *true* - when one of them is *false* the whole statement is *false* as well.</strike>

So, just change to:

```
if(a || b){
    alert('Please select search type');
    return false;
}
```

And it should do what you want.

**Edit:** sorry, got confused myself with the boolean logic.

From [quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/mKALq/) your code does work exactly as-is: only when no checkbox is ticked the alert shows up.

Please explain what is the problem and steps to reproduce in the jsFiddle if possible and we'll see.

Comment: wrong, you can transform every `or` operator to an `and` operator, and vice versa.

Comment: @duedl0r sure, I can negate the whole thing but for what purpose? Why insist on using `and`?

Comment: @shadow:it will show alert message even when one of the radio button is selected. so not applicable.\

Comment: @ShadowWizard: why do you insist on using `or`? :) you can also use `xor` (formaly `or` is also wrong, but that's a different story). And you're current solution is wrong: he negated his variables..

Comment: @duedl0r you're totally right, got confused here. The original code actually works (see my edit for test case) so guess something else is the problem.